# How to define default value for map variable in Terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My input.tfvars file has the values for map variable named project as below:

```
project = {
name = "sampleproject"
team = "Code"
}
```

The definition for the same variable project for default values in variables.tf file is below:

```
variable "project"{
type = map(string)
default ={
name = "defaultproject"
team = "defaultteam"
}
}
```

Is the syntax for defining default variables is correct? or does the key also needs to be provided in quotes as below:

```
variable "project"{
type = map(string)
default ={
"name" = "defaultproject"
"team" = "defaultteam"
}
}
```

Google search provided answers with both of the above options for defining default variables for a map, hence I am asking here for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keys in HCL2 Maps and Objects must be strings, and therefore any key is implicitly cast to String, and therefore does not need the explicit syntax for casting/constructing as a string i.e. `""`.

Note the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/types#maps-objects) confirms keys must be String type.